# Displaying positive symbol for positive elements in MATLAB array?

Tags: string, matlab

I have an array in MATLAB, and I wanted to display the positive symbol, "+" in front of positive elements, and keep the negative symbol, "-" in already existing negative values. I thought I could do the following:

I was thinking of constructing a sort of cell string or string array, and having an if, else system where if the numbers magnitude was >0, then I should store the value as '+' concatenated with the conversion of the element. If it was 0, just do a straight up char conversion since 0 has no sign, and if it was negative, just convert it. I know what to do, however, logistically, I think my order of commands is whacky.

How can I implement this?

I have the following *script* for an array x, but it just spews out values, I want an orderly string array I can copy and paste for use outside of MATLAB.

```
x;
pos = '+';

bound = length(x);

for i=1:bound
  if(x(i)==0)
    num2str(x(i))
end

if(x(i)>0)
    num2str(x(i))
    strcat(pos,num2str(x(i)))
end

if(x(i)<0)
    num2str(x(i))
    strcat(pos,num2str(x(i)))
end

end
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @excaza Sorry! I forgot that part. I added it. It's been a long day. I also updated it with an attempt at the solution.

Comment: [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#input_argument_formatspec) allows you to specify a `+` flag to always print the sign for each value (`fprintf` is the same). Without a sample input and the desired output there isn't really much to go on.

Comment: @excaza

That's much better! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for this.

Let's make an example.

First type in your command window :

```
test = 5;
```

Then:

```
sprintf('%+d',test)
```

You should have in this way what you want. 
Of course you need to adapt it to your case. I suggest you to read [this](http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html).

I hope it helps.

Comment: I like this implementation. Thanks!